# OS X no longer sees my DVD drive. How to debug this?

Tags: hardware, mac-pro, dvd

My Mac Pro has its original built-in DVD burner, which has always seemed to work fine in the past.  Sometime in the recent past (10.9.1?), it simply disappeared.

I first noticed that pressing the eject button on my keyboard didn't do anything.  I looked up alternative ways to eject the tray, and I found the "drutil" program, which seems to confirm that OS X doesn't see any drives at all:

```
$ drutil list
   Vendor   Product           Rev   Bus       SupportLevel

$
```

I've rebooted, and that doesn't help.  I don't even know how to debug this.  Where do I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted *a second time*, and now it works.  Crazy.